# Chrome windows randomly jump between desktops on Windows login

Tags: windows, windows-10, google-chrome

The following behavior started a few months ago:

Whenever I unlock Windows [1], Chrome [2] windows sometimes get randomly reassigned to another virtual desktop instead of sticking to the one they were open in before.

I was under the impression that this behavior had started with the introduction of Chrome's new title bar so I tried to force-enable/disable the `Custom-drawn Windows 10 Titlebar` flag but that didn't fix the problem.

I haven't seen this issue being mentioned anywhere.

Any idea what's causing this and how to fix it?

EDIT: Opened a ticket on Chromium's issue tracker:
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=908407

---

[1] Windows 10 Pro, version 1803 (OS build 17134.285), using 3 virtual desktops
[2] Chrome version 70.0.3538.77 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: What do you mean by "unlock"?

Comment: After some inactivity, your session will be locked. You can also lock it by pressing Ctrl+Alt+Del and choosing Lock. By unlocking, I mean entering my password on the lock screen.